# Can't change resolution or can't detect monitor

Tags: debian, xrandr, laptop, monitors, troubleshooting

The computer is a MSI Gl63 8RD. I installed Debian 9 on it. When I booted it it had a very low resolution. Upon executing `xrandr`, this outputted:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 800 x 600, current 800 x 600, maximum 800 x 600
default connected primary 800x600+0+0 0mm x 0mm
800x600       75.00*
```

According to the computer specs, it should be able to get 1920x1080 resolution. the output of `xrandr --listmonitors` was:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Monitors: 1
0: +*default 800/212x600/159+0+0  default
```

And output of `lspci | grep VGA` :

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3e9b
```

I tried xrandr --newmode and --addmode, but then when trying to change to 1920x1080 resolution I got the message: "could not set the configuration for CRTC 86".

One thing I noticed is if go to system setup (BIOS) before booting the resolution is good. I also tried to see what happens if I installed ubuntu, and everything works fine. What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Why the downvote? Is there anything I should improve in the question or is it unsuited here?

Comment: I believe it has something to do to debian using a older kernel and lack of compatibility with nvidia OPTIMUS. Something like that?